# How do I pass a airplane row and seat to a txt file together with its passenger name etc.?

Tags: c, struct

We need to make a program for airplane seat reservation. Like we need a program which can reserve, change, delete, and display seats. But our program needs also to be written in a txt file as the user inputs data (name, age, city, seat-e.g., 1F). And I have made a program myself. It runs but  exits halfway. And I am not sure if what I'm doing is right. I kind of get the gist on how I can pass informations using structs. But I don't know how I will the seats also in the txt file.

I have these on my first lines:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>

struct Passenger{
    int pnum;
    int age;
    char city[50];
    char name[50];
    };

struct Seats{
    int row;
    char seats[10];
};

struct Airplane{
    struct Seats seats[6];
};

void intializeDefault(struct Airplane *airplane){
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        char ch='A';
        airplane->seats[i].row=i+1;
        for(int j=0;j<6;j++){
            airplane->seats[i].seats[j]=ch;
            ch++;
        }
    }
}
```

And well we kind of have commands, so I put it like:

```
int main(){
    int ch;
    struct Airplane airplane;
    intializeDefault(&airplane);
    do{
        printf("Welcome to our Airlines!\n");
        
        printf("\nOptions:");
        printf("\n[1] Book a seat.");
        printf("\n[2] Display seats.");
        printf("\n[3] Change seat.");
        printf("\n[4] Delete reservation.");
        printf("\n[5] Display reservation records.");
        printf("\n[0] Exit.");
        printf("\nWhat can we do for you? (Enter number.):  ");
        scanf("%d", &ch);
    
        switch(ch){
            case 1:book();
                break;
            case 2:display(&airplane);
                break;
            case 3:change();
                break;
            case 4:deleteSeat();
                break;
            case 5:record();
            break;
            default:    
                break;  
        }
    }while (ch!=0);
    {
        printf("\nThank you for booking !");
    };

    return 0;
}
```

What I need help on is how should I do on this part:

```
void book(){
    struct Passenger *p;
    FILE *fp;
    
    struct Airplane airplane;
    intializeDefault(&airplane);
    int totalSeats = 60;
    int seatsBooked = 0;
    int n, i, j, row;
    char seat;
    printf("How many passengers/seats you want to reserve?: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    
    p = (struct Passenger*) malloc(n * sizeof(struct Passenger));
    
    fp=fopen("Passengers.txt", "w");
    
    if(seatsBooked==60){
            printf("\nAll seats are booked now.");
        }
        
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("Enter Roll Number: ");
        scanf("%d", p[i].pnum);
        
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Enter #%d passenger's name: ", i+1);
        scanf("%[^\n]s", p[i].name);
        
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("What's the passenger's age?: ");
        scanf("%d", p[i].age);
    
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Please enter the city where the passenger resides: ");
        scanf("%d",p[i].city);
                
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\nEnter Seat row: (Type 1-10) ");
        scanf("%d", &row);
                
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Enter Seat column: (Type A-F) ");
        scanf("%c", &seat);
        
            
        if(airplane.seats[row-1].seats[seat-'A']!='X'){
        airplane.seats[row-1].seats[seat-'A']='X';
        seatsBooked++;
        printf("\nSeat %d%c is booked. \n\n", row, seat);
                    }
        else{
            printf("\nSeat %d%c is already booked.\n", row, seat);
            }
        
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

I just need to know on how I can also pass every passenger's seats within on them, and I think I will figure out the other parts. It's because we need to show the records of passengers and their seat reservations when we command "5", and I need to show "X" on every reserved seats when we command "2". And I am not quite sure how I will do that. Should I change the functions on above? The structs? Or some lines?

Comment: Looks like the program is written in C language rather then C++. Please correct the tag.

Comment: Yes, it's C language. I'm very sorry, I didn't notice.

Answer (score 0):

I gave a quick look and I think that you should keep track of the booked seat by *the single user*... In your "Seats" struct, why don't you add an array of "Passenger" pointers in order to link every seat to the respective user?
As soon a user books a seat, you should have the index of the booked seat in a specific row. You take the char array and you put an 'X' in that position. Then you take the Passenger* array and in the same position you assign the address of that client's Passenger object.

Comment: sure, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The one suggestion I would make is to pass along your airplane structure to your various functions.  For example:

```
    switch(ch){
        case 1:book(&airplane);
        break;
```

Then, down in your "book" function you would use the airplane structure in your code.

```
void book(Airplane *airplane){
    struct Passenger *p;
    FILE *fp;

    //struct Airplane airplane; /* Or just remove this line of code */
```

You might want to repeat the referencing of the airplane structure in your other functions as well.

Hope that helps.

Regards.